# Laravel saved file/image in shared hosting got wrong directory

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function to upload files. on Localhost it's not having an error. but after I deploy on shared hosting, its have a problem. If localhost, I'm not moving some folder, but on "tutorial" shared hosting, I need to make 2 folders. *Laravel* and *public*. this *Laravel* folder is all file on project *Laravel* **without *public***

It's my schema on my shared hosting

(/home/sippausr)

etc

Laravel ->

- app
- bootstrap
- config
- database
- public_html

  - files ( this file saved here)
- resources
- routes
- storage
- tests
- vendor

logs

mail

public_ftp

public_html ->

- css
- files (not on here, i need to save here)
- home
- images
- js
- kalibrasi
- public
- sop
- theme

And I have a function to upload a file and saved this file to directory *files* on *public_html* like this

```
public function store6(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        
    ]);
    if($request->hasfile('image')) {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move(public_path().'/files/', $name);  
        $data = $name;  
    }
    
    $user = new pemeliharaan;
    $id = Auth::user()->id;

    $user->user_id = $id;
    $user->alat_id = $request->alat_id;
    $user->pertanyaan =json_encode($request->except
    (['_token','name','alat_id','status','catatan','image']));
    $user->catatan = $request->catatan;
    $user->image=$data;
    $user->status = $request->status;
    $user->save();
    // dd($user);
    return redirect('user/show6')->with('success', 'Data Telah Terinput');
}
```

But, this file **not saved** at `public_html/files`,

This file saved in the Laravel folder, on *public_html*( you can see at schema). Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to save your file to your `files` directory in your `public` folder.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class YourClassName  implements Contract {

    public function store6(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            
        ]);
        if($request->hasfile('image')) {
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            Storage::putFileAs('public/files', $file, $name);
            $data = $name;  
        }

        $user = new pemeliharaan;
        $id = Auth::user()->id;

        $user->user_id = $id;
        $user->alat_id = $request->alat_id;
        $user->pertanyaan =json_encode($request->except
        (['_token','name','alat_id','status','catatan','image']));
        $user->catatan = $request->catatan;
        $user->image=$data;
        $user->status = $request->status;
        $user->save();
        return redirect('user/show6')->with('success', 'Data Telah Terinput');
    }
}
```

Comment: its not solution , this file located in  
 
storage 

 
app
 
public
 
files

Comment: So what are you trying to do?

Comment: i need this file is saved on public_html , i think i can use base_path but i dont know how to do